# Firebase Functions - Log not reachable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried to read out the Firebase Functions Log, but I can not reach them. Normally they were reachable through the firebase console. A couple of days ago there was still a tab in the top menu bar which is now gone:

[image]

Is there any information I didn't see or is it moved to Google Cloud?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll need to use Google Cloud Functions console to view the logs now as in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there anywhere an official statement by Google that I have missed? In Google Cloud I couldn’t find a filter solution for the different function logs yet.

Comment: The screenshot in that answer is from Firebase console that was shown a few days back.